# SonarQube Custom Widget

Tags: java, maven, widget, sonarqube

I'm new to SonarQube and have been attempting for the majority of the day to create a simple "Hello World" SonarQube widget to prove a widget can be created (it will be enhanced later).

I've created a maven project following the guidelines at;

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Build+plugin

I've also looked at the documentation here;

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Web+Application

However, when I build the java code and deploy to the plugins folder on the SonarQube server the service errors loading the plugin with the error;

*java.lang.ClassCastException:  cannot be cast to org.sonar.api.plugin*

I have declared my class as the following;

*public class MyPOC extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements RubyRailsWidget {*

Does anyone have a working example of a sonarQube UI widget plugin - or assist in anyway.  SonarQube does look like a fantastic tool - but its documentation seems to be lacking (or the API versions mixed up on the web searches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a link to a sample project https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples

Answer (score -1):

look at your pom.xml, make sure you configure correct plugin class. You can check under tag:

> build --> plugins --> plugin --> configuration --> pluginclass.

**Note:** plugin class is class that implements org.sonar.api.Plugin